# How to check if file field is empty in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a form with a file field called `image`, but this field is not required.
When user don't choose any file in form, the `do_upload()` always return a error.
How can I check if user chosen a file before perform the upload action in my controller?

Comment: Just remove the `required` rule if you have declared it in the  validation rules

Comment: I don't have require validation for this field.

Comment: Then you shouldn't get any error when user doesn't choose any file in the form.. What's the error exactly?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Please use **empty()**

```
if (empty($_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
}
```

Comment: It's $_FILES (plural), and why not? Your form is submitted to a function in the controller which means that all the super_globals (i.e $_POST and $_FILES) are available within the scope of the function

Comment: Sorry guys, my fault, I was check $_FILE in singular.. =/

Comment: @VinothBabu, 1. he needs to check first if it exists. 2. he should test for NOT empty

Comment: @Matanya: yes need to check isset

Answer (score 6):

Try to check if the file is valid using [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php). For example:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) 
{  
   do_upload();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer. In above two answer solution given are very simple that are first guess solutions. this is a gem answer.

Answer (score 5):

In your controller, on the function that receives the submitted form:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    // do_upload

}
```

Comment: The `isset` is redundant. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php): `empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false`

Answer (score 1):

Here is full script to check if file field is empty or not in php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input name="my_files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>


<?php

 if (isset($_FILES['my_files']))
  {
    $myFile = $_FILES['my_files'];
    $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);


        for ($i = 0; $i <$fileCount; $i++)
         {
           $error = $myFile["error"][$i]; 

            if ($error == '4')  // error 4 is for "no file selected"
             {
               echo "no file selected";
             }
            else
             {

               $name =  $myFile["name"][$i];
               echo $name; 
               echo "<br>"; 
               $temporary_file = $myFile["tmp_name"][$i];
               echo $temporary_file;
               echo "<br>";
               $type = $myFile["type"][$i];
               echo $type;
               echo "<br>";
               $size = $myFile["size"][$i];
               echo $size;
               echo "<br>";



               $target_path = "uploads/$name";   //first make a folder named "uploads" where you will upload files


                 if(move_uploaded_file($temporary_file,$target_path))
                  {
                   echo " uploaded";
                   echo "<br>";
                   echo "<br>";
                  }
                   else
                  {
                   echo "no upload ";
                  }




              }
        }  
}
        ?>


</body>
</html>
```

But be alert. User can upload any type of file and also can hack your server or system by uploading a malicious or php file. In this script there should be some validations.

refer http://www.techzigzag.com/how-to-check-that-user-has-upload-any-file-or-not-in-php/

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use native php code to check file upload.

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'])) {
echo 'No upload';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) empty function does check if the file field is empty or not

```
if ( ! empty($_FILES)) {...}


if(!empty($_FILES['myFileField'])) {
    // file field is not empty..
} else {
    // no file uploaded..
}
```

Comment: Where I use empty()? I can't access $_FILE or $this->input for the field.

Comment: I can't access $_FILE into Codeigniter Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

As file upload error "No file selected" is number 4, correct way of doing this is:

```
if ($_FILES['my_image_field_name']['error'] !== 4){
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('my_image_field_name')) { ...
```

When checking by name or tmp_name, there might be other reasons why these fields didn't get populated, and you may miss these.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_FILES[$file_name]['name'])){
  // TODO your logic

}else{
  echo "empty";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file['file']->isValid()
```

[CI4 user guide link](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/uploaded_files.html#verify-a-file)